# WiFi not working in secure mode Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, secure-boot

I am totally new to Ubuntu and Linux in general.

When I first installed Ubuntu (switching from Windows 8.1), the first problem I noticed was that my WiFi was not working. I found a solution for it. I installed drivers for my wireless LAN, and started my system in insecure mode. Later on, when I changed back to secure mode I still can't turn on my WiFi (actually there is no option for it).

I tried `rfkill`, but it didn't work.
Here is the output of `rfkill list` in insecure mode:

[image: screenshot]

When I do `rfkill list` in secure mode, it doesn't show 2nd and 3rd one (both Wireless LAN).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secure boot requires that all software and any added kernel modules, also commonly known as drivers, have a known, registered signing key in order to load. The Broadcom STA driver that your wireless devices requires doesn't yet have a signing key. You can either just disable secure boot or tell Ubuntu to disable secure boot in Ubuntu only using `mokutil`. Here are some details: [Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules/762255#762255)

As a 15-year user of Linux and Ubuntu, I am quite comfortable running a simple desktop machine behind a firewall-enabled router without secure boot.

Comment: So does that mean I won't be able to use wifi in secure mode?

Comment: It means that exactly until Broadcom issues a driver package with a proper signing key.